# How to query Fusion Tables to produce a feature layer with the ArcGIS Android SDK?

Tags: android, google-fusion-tables, sdk, arcgis-android

I am hoping to find an example of how one can hook into Fusion Tables with the ArcGIS Android SDK.

The Fusion Tables API uses HTTP GET requests to query and retrieve data from a table. Shown here: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#Select

This returns a JSON data that can hopefuly be consumed by the ArcGIS Android SDK.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind a 3rd party app, you could try [Arc2Earth Sync](http://www.arc2earth.com/services/sync/)

It will connect to Fusion Tables on your account's behalf and make it look like an ArcGIS Feature service. It can also use your ArcGIS.com credentials to create/update web maps so your FT tables show up automatically in the ArcGIS iOS/Android apps (or any of the ArcGIS Online apps/apis).

Check out the sample [here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=e1cdc4855ea54edf8ff9451e32fff5cb). And here's the [same data](http://geojason.info/google-vector-layers/demos/arc2earth/) used on Google Maps directly from the [Fusion Table](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=2447544)

We've got a big update coming out soon too. Image tiles, vector tiles, UTF grids are all automatically created/updated when your data changes and then hosted for you (or move the caches wherever you like). New providers for [Fulcrum](http://fulcrumapp.com/), [CartoDB](http://cartodb.com/) and plain ole local shapefiles make it really easy to get started and work with your data in ArcGIS Online.

cheers
brian